# Calling free() on a dynamically allocated array in C seems to be changing data stored in another array?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following C code:

```
char *a, *b;
int count;
a = malloc(10);
b = malloc(10);
for(count=0;count<10;count++){
  b[count] = 'a';}
memcpy(&a, &b, 10);
for(count=0;count<10;count++){
  printf("%c %c\n", a[count], b[count]);}
free(b);
for(count=0;count<10;count++){
  printf("%c, ", a[count]);}
```

However, in the output, the first 8 elements of the array a seem to be deleted by freeing up b:

```
./a.out
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
a a
, , , , , , , , a, a,
```

Could someone please try and explain what's happening here? I can't seem to find a reason for this happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't actually reproduce your problem (in Visual Studio/MSVC), but there is a problem (and almost certainly undefined behaviour) caused by this line:

```c
memcpy(&a, &b, 10);
```

The `a` and `b` variables are *already* pointers, so you don't need to pass their addresses to `memcpy`. Just use:

```c
memcpy(a, b, 10);
```

In your code, you could be overwriting the address value stored in both/either of the pointers.

EDIT: The `clang-cl` compiler spots the problem, giving this:

> warning : 'memcpy' will always overflow; destination buffer has size
>   8, but size argument is 10 [-Wfortify-source]

Answer (score 3):

The `free(b)` is not the problem, the line:

```
memcpy(&a, &b, 10);
```

Should be:

```
memcpy(a, b, 10);
```

`a` and `b` are already pointers to memory locations, you shouldn't pass their adresses, this will lead to undefined behaviour.